# how to post a Photo or link on facebook wall without using FBSDK in android

Tags: android, facebook

Want to post some photos or link on user Facebook wall without using FBSDKShareDialog. I am already post with using the FBSDKSharePhoto And FBSDKShareDialog defult dialog from facebook. For that I do the below code.

Comment: where is the code can you post the code .

Comment: Are you need to share the Data From Your App to Facebook App without FBSDk ?

Comment: Could the upvoter please explain how this is useful and clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the dialogs (regardless of whether you invoke them using the SDK or your own code), you will have to resort to using Graph API.

In order to create posts using Graph API, you will have to POST to the `/me/feed` endpoint ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish)), but that [requires an access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#pubperms).

In order to obtain an access token from Facebook, you need to implement Facebook login, and their [Platform Policy section 7.2](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#login) says:

> Native iOS and Android apps that implement Facebook Login must use our official SDKs for login.

So in the end, you might as well use their SDK after all, or risk your app getting blocked.

---

However, assuming you have an access token and you are using the SDK (but not the dialog - since that is what you are actually asking), you can [use this docs section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph) to learn about how you can make Graph API calls using the SDK.